# Is ubuntu 12.04 still supported?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I tried to find out till when ubuntu 12.04 is supported. It supposed to be the April 2017. But which date exactly? 
Where can I find the exact date?

Comment: If support ends April 17, then wouldn't it be best looking for a replacement, rather than worrying about the precise date...?

Comment: The problem is, that some programs are not supported any more. And updating the System would mean losing the programs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no exact date for the end of support in the Ubuntu documentation. I think you can assume it will happen in the release anniversary date, and, according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29), will be on April 26. You can use the following command in bash to check the status of your installed version:

`$ ubuntu-support-status`

as recommended by [this Ubuntu release end-of-life article](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 reaches the end of life on 28 April 2017.

Source: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2017-March/003777.html

Also, see the [versions table on English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Table_of_versions).